# Delete files from SERVER through web interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, server

I need to create a web interface where users can upload files, view info about those (already stored) files and delete them. I've already written the first two parts (I use Node.js server), but I'm having serious problems with deleting stored files.

My main problem is, that I don't know, how to make a request with info about the file user want to delete correctly. I supposed that I will simply use `open()` method like this

```
xhr.open('POST', '/delete', true);
```

and then just "catch" it with condition in server code like this:

```
if (req.url == '/delete' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {th
```

But this solutions keeps throwing `error 404 - Resource not found`.

So, could you please help me and describe some way which works for you?

---

Here is my [server code](http://pastebin.com/cmZgSmrL).

And this file contains [client-side JavaScript](http://pastebin.com/0JVUHxun).
- there is the problem in function `createStoredFilesTable()` in `$('.deleteLink').click()` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple in the end - the problem was missing "return" in the end of DELETE block, so the program handled the request and continued to loading source codes, where it couldn't find anything, because request URL was '/delete'.

So, the correct block of the server code is here:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- DELETE handling ---//
//-----------------------//
if (req.url == '/delete' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        var filename = data.toString('ascii');
        var jsonObj = require('./storedFilesList.json');
        delete jsonObj[filename];
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        fs.writeFile('storedFilesList.json', jsonString, function(err){
            if (err) throw err;
            fs.unlinkSync(__dirname + '/uploadedFiles/' + filename);
            console.log('File ' + filename + ' was succesfully deleted.');
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('OK');
        res.end();
    });
    return;
}
```